# What is the total numbers of chocolates belonging to three of them?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, puzzle

> **Pial** gives half of his **20** chocolates to **Zunayed** so that **Zunayed** has more chocolates, **Zunayed** gives half of his chocolates to **Bindu** so that **Bindu** has more chocolates than
>   **Zunayed**. What is the total numbers of chocolates belonging to three of them?

Source: [Bangladesh Math Olympiad 2018 junior category](https://www.matholympiad.org.bd/).

I can not understand the question properly. "Zunayed has more chocolates"- does it mean he has more chocolate than both Pial and Bindu or only Pial. Is there any valid solution of this question?

Comment: In my opinion, it means "Zunayed has more chocolates than Pial."

Comment: But don't you think that this makes the puzzle with unlimited values. Like if Pial have 20, Zunayed has 30 and Bindu has 60 the answer will be correct if any values for Pial < Zunayed < Bindu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming **Zunayed** has more chocolates than **Pial** and at the end it is not required to have $P<Z<B$, but only the intermediate steps. (**Pial** is not to blame if **Zunayed** decided to give away chocolates to **Bindu**).

> **Pial** gives half of his **20** chocolates to **Zunayed** so that **Zunayed** has more chocolates (than **Pial**).

Can **Zunayed** have **3** chocolates? No, because **Pial** can give **9** chocolates so that $Z=12>11=P$. (According to the condition, **Pial** must give **10** and keep $\color{red}{10}$).

Can **Zunayed** have **2** chocolates? Yes, Zunayed has $\color{red}{2}$ chocolates.

Can **Zunayed** have **1** chocolate? No, because **Zunayed** gets **10** from Pial to have **11** in total, however, **Zunayed** can not give half of it to **Bindu** (it is assumed a chocolate is indivisible).

> **Zunayed** gives half of his chocolates to **Bindu** so that **Bindu** has more chocolates than **Zunayed**.

First note that **Zunayed** has **12** chocolates after receiving **10** from **Pial**.

Can **Bindu** have **3** chocolates? No, because **Zunayed** has **12** chocolates and **Zunayed** can give **5** to **Bindu**, because $B=8>7=Z$. (According to the condition, **Zunayed** must give **6**).

Can **Bindu** have **2** or **1** chocolates? Yes, **Bindu** has $\color{red}{2}$ or $\color{red}{1}$ chocolates.

Hence, the total number of chocolates is $\color{red}{24}$ or $\color{red}{23}$. That is: 
$$P=20,Z=2,B=2 \ \ \text{or} \ \ P=20,Z=2,B=1$$
in the beginning.

Comment: I am sorry, but don't you think that only Pial have 20 chocolates, then how the total number of chocolates are 14 or 13?

Comment: You are right, I mistakenly took $P=10$, fixed.

Comment: Could you please explain why Zynayed's number of chocolates is not more than Pial? Actually I am struggling at that part.

Comment: It states "Pial gives half of his so that Zynayed has more than Pial" implying initially Pial had more than Zynayed. Similarly, once Zynayed gets chocolates from Pial, Zynayed will have more than Bindu, therefore Zynayed is giving to Bindu. So, there are several assumptions I am using. Even these restrictive assumptions does not produce unique solution.

Comment: I followed the link you provided, could access BDMO2017, but BDMO2018 is not downloadable. BDMO was in hindi. Did you translate the problem yourself accurately? Does it provide the correct answer, so that we can guess their assumptions?

Comment: https://www.matholympiad.org.bd/resources/all-questions/category/18-bdmo-2018     Just download the zip file, extract it and then in set-01 you will find this question in page 03. In every question it is translated to English from Bangla (not Hindi!).

Answer (score 0):

I read it to mean that after the first transfer Zunayed has more than Pial has left. 
 In that case the problem is not well posed.  As long as Zunayed starts with a positive even number of chocolates and Bindu starts with at least one the transfers will satisfy the requirements.  After the first Pial has $10$ and Zunayed has however many he started with plus $10$, so more than Pial.  After the second transfer Bindu has more than Zunayed by the number he started with.